# Hilarious badge animation in achievements view of iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, ios-app, achievements-dialog

Every time I pull to refresh the achievements view, my badges get bigger. Does this mean they're going supernova?

> [image]

Comment: Better evacuate the solar system just in case...

Comment: Did you spend unicoins to purchase a bigger medal?

Comment: This isn't a bug; it's a feature.

Comment: @mhlester are you on version 1.0.1.78?

Comment: @ArieLitovsky I think so, but the sidebar still calls it 1.0.1.73...

Comment: @Arie, 1.0.1.79 also still calls itself 1.0.1.73

Comment: @mhlester ok, we'll have to look into what's wrong with the version setup

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the report. I was incorrectly using a font size which was a factor of the previously set font size, causing the effect you saw.

This will be fixed in **1.0.1.79**.

Comment: Oh no! You misunderstand! I **love** this feature and want the desktop to have it too! Now you've gone and taken it from me. **-1**